# Google Coral Environmental Sensor Board reports NaN for all measurements

Tags: google-coral

When running the Google Coral Environmental Sensor Board on a fresh Raspbian install and fresh installation of the Google Coral Raspberry Pi library, all measurements are NaN (not a number) when running the Google demo code.

Is this an indication that the board is broken, even if the display works fine?

Reinstalled Raspbian OS on a Raspberry Pi 0 w and reinstalled Coral Raspberry Pi library.

Google demo code is here:
https://coral.googlesource.com/coral-cloud/+/refs/heads/master/python/coral-enviro/coral/enviro/enviro_demo.py

No errors reported

Comment: This thread has a suggested solution which some claim worked for them.  It is essentially a re-install of Raspbian and the Google Coral libraries, but it did not work for me.

https://github.com/f0cal/google-coral/issues/21

Comment: Can you share the output of uname -a from your raspberry pi ?

Comment: uname -a responds with:
Linux rasberrypi 4.19.57+ #1244 Thu Jul 4 18:42:50 BST 2019 armv61 GNU/Linux

Comment: I updated to the latest Raspian Buster, version 4.19.57+ #1244, and still get NaNs for all values.

Comment: Can you go through : https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu-platforms. I believe the issue with Buster has been fixed.

Comment: Sorry, I followed all the steps listed for the edgetpu platforms and I am still getting NaN for all values.